# How to plot 3 graphs using values arranged in columns in a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: matlab, graph, matrix

I have written code with the help of SO that plots values of k_12 agaist the frequncy. 
However, now I need to plot 3 graphs, one for each frequency with the value of of k_12 on the x-axis and the corresponding 3 mode shapes on the y-axis. The modes shapes are arranged in columns in matrix V for each frequency. This is the piece of code:

```
M = [3 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 0.5]    % mass matrix

i_vals = 1:1000:60e07;    % values of k_12 from 1 to 60 million in steps of 1000
freq = zeros(3, length(i_vals));

for n=1:length(i_vals)
    i = i_vals(n)    % i is the value of k_12
    K = [i+8e06 -i -2e06; -i i+2e06 -1e06; -2e06 -1e06 5e06];    % stiffness matrix

    [V,L]=eig(K,M);     
    values=diag(L);     
    [values,I]=sort(values);    
    V(:,I)=V;               % V is the mode shapes matrix (3x3)
    freq(:, n)=sqrt(values)/(2*pi); 

end
h = loglog(i_vals, freq');
    title('Effect of change of value of k_1_2 on the value of natural frequency');
    xlabel('Value of k_1_2 [N/m]');
    ylabel('Value of natural frequency [Hz]');
    hleg1 = legend('\omega_n_r_1','\omega_n_r_2', '\omega_n_r_3');
    grid on;
    grid minor;
```

I know I have to add three lines with

```
loglog(i_vals, "something")
loglog(i_vals, "something 2")
loglog(i_vals, "something 3")
```

The problem is that I do not know what to write in that "something". 
Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT:**
I must have explained myself incorrectly, what I want to do is to plot 3 different graphs with the values of mode shapes for the corresponding frequency, that is to say, given

```
    "Frequencies [Hz]
      186.6438  331.3465  514.6650

    Mode shape vectors in the columns of matrix [V]
%       1st freq  2nd freq  3rd freq
        0.3285    0.4578   -0.1257
        0.5640   -0.4219   -0.0627
        0.2831    0.1743    1.3746"
```

I want to have obtain a graph of the 1st frequency and the corresponding mode shapes (first column), for the 2nd frequeny and the corresponding mode shapes and so on.

**EDIT 2**
The piece of code I posted changes the value of stiffness k and plots the 3 frequencies 
[image: graph]
In other words, it plots the values of 3 frequencies from the frequency matrix on the same graph:

[image: matrix]

What I would like to do now is to plot values of stiffness k on the x-axis and the values of the mode shapes on the y-axis, that is to say, a1, a2 and a3; on the second graph, stiffness k against b1, b2 and b3 and on the third graph stiffness k against c1, c2 and c3. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to separate graphs? `h = loglog(i_vals, freq(1,:)');` should help.

Comment: If you want to do what Pavel Oganesyan assumes, don't forget to write:
`loglog(i_vals, "something"); hold on` and
 `loglog(i_vals, "something 3"); hold off`. 

If you want to plot separate figure for each frequency write: `subplot(3,1,1);
loglog(i_vals, freq(1,:)');
subplot(3,1,2); 
loglog(i_vals,freq(2,:)'); 
subplot(3,1,3); 
loglog(i_vals, freq(3,:)');`

Comment: @Ergodicity could you please see the EDIT? I must have explained myself incorrectly. Nevertheless, your answer is very helpful.

Comment: I'm still not shure what you want to do. Maybe you can break down your problem to a simplified example.

Comment: @Ergodicity I added EDIT 2; hope it clear this time. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you wish three individual graphs, you will also need to call `figure` before each plot or it will just overwrite the previous graph.

You can use the `freq( rowNumber , : )` notation to access an individual row, which holds one of your data sets (replace `rowNumber` with the numeric value of the row).

If we combined everything and add line colours that are the same as the plot of all three data sets (using the third parameter of `loglog` here) we get:

```
figure;
loglog(i_vals, freq(1,:),'b');
% Add titles, scales, gridlines, etc here...
figure;
loglog(i_vals, freq(2,:),'g');
% Add titles, scales, gridlines, etc here...
figure;
loglog(i_vals, freq(3,:),'r');
% Add titles, scales, gridlines, etc here...
```

Of course, you will need to add legends, correct scales, gridlines, and other aids to understanding to each figure individually as required.

This could be wrapped up in a `for` loop but i feel this expanded style gives a better outline of what is happening.

Comment: Could you please see the EDIT? I must have explained myself incorrectly. Nevertheless, your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a complicated problem and large data. You really should learn the basics of MATLAB in a tutorial (there are lots of). You are doing a lot of beginner's mistake - and I think SO is to help you but not for doing your work.

So I will give you only some hints:

- You can't plot V, because you overwrite it every loop. You should keep all your values in one variable (which thean has three dimensions). You can use a cell array in the following way:

  a{1} = [1,2;3,4];

  a{2} = [10,20;30,40];

  a{2} = (2,2)

  for more information about cell array ask Google ;-)
- Try to avoid loops. They make you code sooooo slow.
- Add a ";" at the end of line 7. It will speed up your code, too.
- Try everything with little examples first. Then you will understand how each step works.
- I'm not shure how you want to plot three values (a1,a2,a3) over one variable. You should describe this in more detail.

Good luck!